# Merge columns based with date column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, merge, matlab, r

I have an excel table with several columns(as shown in the attached picture).I want to merge these ROC1,ROC2,ROC3 and ROC5 where the dates match for them.So an ideal row should be Common Date,ROC1,ROC2,ROC3 and ROC3.
I tried Lookup command but I am not able to apply it! Can someone please help!
[ImageExcel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfZqf.jpg)

Comment: How about using Power Query?

Answer (score 0):

I recreated a table similar to the screenshot you provided and came up with the following formula:

```
=IF(AND(A2=D2,A2=G2),DAY(A2)&"/"&MONTH(A2)&"/"&YEAR(A2)&" "&B2&" "&E2&" "&H2&" "&K2,"NO_MATCH")
```

Because it is pulling in dates plus general number values it ended up being pretty clunky, but it does work.

[image]